# Suggestion for applying Inheritence

Tags: java

I'm doing a lesson that is supposed to demonstrate inheritance using the song Old MacDonald; there's an animal interface, a farm class that implements each animal object.. you get the idea. I've got two problems.

1) The animal has a type and a sound, for example, a chick is

```
class Chick implements Animal {
    private String myType;
    private String mySound;
    private String mySound2;
    int flag =0;

    public Chick(String type, String sound)
    {
        myType = type;
        mySound = sound;
    }

    public Chick(String type, String sound,String sound2)
    {
        myType = type;
        mySound = sound;
        mySound2=sound2;
    } 

    public Chick()
    {
        myType = "unknown";
        mySound = "unknown";
    }

    public String getSound() 
    {
        return mySound;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return myType; 
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to create a second constructor with a flag that says whether a chick is childish and returns the sound "cheep" or is adult and returns "cluck" so that there's an equal probability of getSound() returning either. I have no idea how to do this. I considered adding a boolean to the constructor, but that won't work because the farm class can only create a new Chick(); I realize you're not just going to hand me an answer, but I don't even know where to start.

2) The other issue is that I'm supposed to create a NamedCow class that, as you probably guessed, gives the cow a name.

I can't just add a getName method to the cow class, namedCow has to be a new class

```
public class NamedCow extends Cow {

    private String myName;

    NamedCow(String name)
    {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return myName;
    }
```

will you please help me writing the correct code for Chick and Cow class as desired? What changes I have to make in both the classes?

Comment: **Hint:** classes can have more than one constructor.

Comment: Isn't a `Cow` an `Animal`, so that everything ultimately inherits from `Animal`? What about abstract ? I would have everything derive from Animal. If you don't want to give the Animal a name, then don't override `getName`. In the super class, make it blank, for instance.

Comment: What's wrong with `NamedCow`?  Other than that your constructor isn't setting the `type` and `sound`, it looks alright to me

Comment: I have to create a NamedCow constructor with 3 parameters.What will I do??

Comment: While classes can have multiple constructors you may prefer to use [mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java_example).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch and I thought the official name was `setters and getters`

Comment: please help me with the Chick class. How will I return 2 sounds either with equal probability if the two sounds are available in the constructor?? Otherwise I have to return one.

Comment: @user3114849 I think you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @user3114849 As Robert Harvey said, classes can have more than one constructor. So make another constructor with (as you said!) a boolean parameter whether the chick is young or not.. according to that value you will initialize the sound value.

Comment: will anyone please write the getSound() function returning the desired value?

Comment: An animal can have more than one constructor, so a Chick can have a constructor that accepts, say, a `bool young` parm, and a Cow can have a constructor that accepts a `String name` parm.  If the flavor of constructor that's used does not supply the parm, fill in the corresponding instance field with an appropriate default.  If the Chick is supposed to be 50/50 if you don't specify age, make the default initialization a random true/false, using a random number generator.

Comment: please write the demo code for the getSound function. @ Hot Licks

Comment: getName only for the cow? the difference for the sound is only for the chick?

Answer (score 0):

For the Chick problem I would use a random method like:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

use nextBoolean() and pass the result of it into the getSound(boolean isChild) method

Then you check in the getSound() method

```
if (isChild)
   return "cheep";
else 
   return "cluck";
```

If you want a random response from the chicken every time. Just add the random generator to the method

```
String getSound(){

Random r = new Random();

if (r.nextBoolean)
       return "cheep";
    else 
       return "cluck";
}
```

Regarding the cow problem, I would create a cow class that inherits animal and then write a method:
For example something like that:

```
nameCow(String name){
    this.cowName=name;
}
```